# How to make my chart full width inside another div?

Tags: bootstrap-5

So im trying to put this chart full width, but it simple dont change size. i have tried to use flex of bootstrap but its doesnt change the width.

```
<div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade" style="margin: auto; flex-wrap: wrap;">
            <br>
            <center><h3><b style="color:white"> Classifications</b></h3></center><br />
            <div  id="myChart" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-basis:auto">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey there. I notice in the CSS you have used that you're doing a traditional CSS flex. But have you tried using the standard Bootstrap `d-flex` options? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: @CuteCodeRob But where should i put it? I tried to use it in the div containing the chart but it doesnt work.

Comment: Yes that should be the correct way to do it. So it is possible that the chat has it's own width defined? Eg, no matter what you do to the srrounding Div, the chat will always have the same width? I am unsure but, if that is the case, maybe the chart does have a defined width or maybe the columns do but the chart itself is fluid? Check my link above though, it does have a full explanation.